# Scroll between tabs like 'Contacts' app in Android ice cream sandwich

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My app is using the Action Bar navigation properties to display tabs for navigation... but you have to click on the tabs to switch between them, but I would like to change tab just scrolling left or right like in the 'Market' app in Android 4, or the 'Contacts' app, also in the Launcher

Thank you!

Comment: I think I solved... here is a link:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Comment: You can add it as answer and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using `PagerAdapters` and `ViewPager` support: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html